# Node label seems to not update after node deletion using a force layout with d3js

Tags: d3.js

The point of my code is to visualize a dynamic network of people. The data represents people getting in/out the network and having contacts.

I have coupled two of Mike Bostocks algorithms (force layout and multiple focus).

The code is working fine, but there is a little problem when i add or delete a node.

It seems something is not right, but i can't point out what.

When i add 1 2 3 and then delete 1 2 3 it delete (on the screen) the 3 first then the 2 then the 1. But if i print out the nodes it actually delete the 1 2 and 3.

This is where i update the layout:

```
function update(){


  link = svg.selectAll(".link")
      .data(force.links());

  link.enter().append("line")
      .attr("class", "link");
  link.exit().remove();

  node = svg.selectAll(".node")
      .data(force.nodes());

  node2 = node.enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .call(force.drag);

  node2.append("path")
    .style("fill", "white")//function(d, i) { return fill(d.service ); })
    .attr("stroke", function(d) { return d3.rgb(d.state & 1 ? "red" : d.state & 2 ? "orange" : "green") })
    .attr("d", d3.svg.symbol()
              .size(200)
              .type(function(d) { if
                (d.staff == 0) { return "circle"; } else if
                (d.staff == 1) { return "square";}}) 
              );          

  node2.append("text")
    .attr("fill", "black")
    .style("font-size","8px")
    .attr("text-anchor","middle")
    .text(function(d) { return d.iden });

  link.exit().remove();
  node.exit().remove();

  force.start();

}
```

This is my full project : http://jsfiddle.net/Thomas99/vfzLnbfo/

Any help is welcome

Thank you.

Comment: You are modifying the array while iterating over it, i.e. changing the indices while relying on the indices for modification. You shouldn't do that -- get the indices *before* making any modifications and then remove them.

Comment: I fixed this, but it didn't fix the problem. I guess it was not a problem because there was only one deletion and one loop.

Comment: Could be a timing issue then.

Comment: What do you mean by a timming issue ?

Comment: You're running all of the removals at once, so they're not necessarily executed in the order that they are run in.

Comment: long shot. did you fix this ? Ive ran in to the same problem